# Paramaterized SQL C# with DateTimes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to execute a SQL statement that grabs data within a given time period represented by two dates. Although I have verified that the values of the parameters I am swapping the SQL parameters with are the correct values, I am still getting this exception:

> Syntax error converting character string to smalldatetime data type

Here is the C# code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT date, @Data FROM datasite WHERE date > '@Start' and date < '@End'", conn);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", dataType);

var start = dateRange.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
var end = dateRange.EndDate.ToShortDateString();

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", start);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", end);

command.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) { //... }
```

Comment: Pass the `DateTime` itself? `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", dateRange.StartDate);`

Comment: Passing it as a DateTime results in the same Exception, sorry I should've mentioned that in the post.

Comment: Remove those single quotes when using parameters.  `'@Start'` should just be `@Start`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to consider:

1. You do not need to cast the dates using `ToShortDateString()`. Instead, you can simply pass the Date variable as the parameter value: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", dateRange.StartDate);`
2. Your SqlCommand text does not need the single quotes around your `@Start` and `@End` variables. Instead, you can use: `WHERE date > @Start AND date < @End`

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise response. I figured that DateTimes had to be handled like they are when writing raw SQL queries, but these changes fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Best to format the date to a known format for the sql statement
eg.

```
   dateRange.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I tried a few different formats but it still results in the same Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to **remove the single quotes** from the command string.

`"SELECT date, @Data FROM datasite WHERE date > '@Start' and date < '@End'"`

To

`"SELECT date, @Data FROM datasite WHERE date > @Start and date < @End"`